# Getting two Blue DongleRS232s to talk using pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I am new to pyserial and I am trying to get two Blue Dongle RS232s to talk to each other

I have one of them connected to /dev/ttyUSB0 and the other to /dev/ttyUSB1

Both of them are configured to get connected to each other when connected using AT commands. I am sending "hello" message from USB0 dongle to the USB1 dongle over bluetooth link.

Here is my code

```
import serial

ser0 = serial.Serial()`
ser0.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
ser0.baudrate = 57600
ser0.bytesize = 8
ser0.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser0.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE

ser1 = serial.Serial()
ser1.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
ser1.baudrate = 57600
ser1.bytesize = 8
ser1.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser1.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE

try:
    ser0.open()
    print "Connected usb0"
except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
    print "Cannot Connect to usb0"
    ser0.close()

try:
    ser1.open()
    print "Connected usb1"
except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
    print "Cannot Connect to usb0"
    ser1.close()

cmd = "hello!!!\r"
ser0.write(cmd.encode())
print "sent hello"
response = ser1.readline()       
# tried ser1.read(64) as well
print response

ser0.close()
ser1.close()
```

Here is the output:
Connected usb0
Connected usb1
sent hello

It prints upto this line -> print "sent hello"
The code gets stuck after that and there is no response generated

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!
--Aneesh

Comment: typo in the question  -> it should be this -> ser1.port = '/dev/ttyUSB1'
sorry

Comment: What about using a newline `\n` rather than carriage return?

Comment: I tried \n ... doesnt work! I am getting the same problem.... I also tried writing a separate python script that keeps listening to '/dev/ttyUSB1' in a while loop and breaks out when it gets a response.... It is still doing the same thing!

Comment: I do not know the tools you are using; you just opened the usb device but did you connected the two devices? or you've confirmed them already connected.

Comment: I figured it out... I had configured the devices to connect to each other on startup, but they weren't connecting for some reason. So I reconfigured them. The ser.1readline() also required the message to end in \n like Paul said... Thanks for your help!